# Sharing image and text works for messages and mail but not for Pages, Word or TextEdit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this code:

```
let title = "This beach is amazing"
let picture = "UIImage(named:"beach") // the image is valid
let description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam faucibus risus in lectus feugiat, ac posuere felis consectetur."
let item = (title, picture, description)
```

Then I have this on a view

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showShareSheet) {
  if let shareItems = MyAssets.generateDictionaryToShare(item) {
     ShareSheet(activityItems: shareItems) { activityType, completed, returnedItems, error in
       showShareSheet.toggle()
     }
  }
}
```

and finally

```
final class MyAssets {

  static func generateDictionaryToShare(_ item:Item) -> [Any]? {
    guard let title = item.title,
          let fullDescription = item.fullDescription,
          let image = item.image
    else { return nil }
    
    
    return [title, "\n\n", fullDescription, image]
  }
```

What this does is:

1. iOS share sheet appears
2. If I select to send it through email or message, the message is composed correctly, firts the title, then the description, then the image.
3. If I choose copy, the contents are copied through iCloud. If I paste it on Pages, MS-Word of a rich text on TextEdit only the image is pasted.

How can I fix that?